# cohomology ring of the fundamental group of unordered configuration space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, configuration-spaces

From the lecture notes [INTRODUCTION TO CONFIGURATION SPACES AND THEIR
APPLICATIONS,](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~sjack/prosem/Cohen_Singapore.final.24.december.2008.pdf) p. 18, I find:
[image]

Os it possible to derive the cohomology ring $H^*(Conf(S,k)/\Sigma_k;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ from the above theorem?

**Question 1:** Given a surface $S$, are there any methods to compute the fundamental group of $k$-th unordered configuration space
$$
\pi_1(Conf(S,k)/\Sigma_k)?
$$

**Question 2:** Given a group $G=\pi_1(Conf(S,k)/\Sigma_k)$, I find 
$
K(G,1)=BG.
$
Are there any methods to compute the cohomology ring (cup product structure)
$$
H^*(BG;\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

Answer (score 1):

- Question 1 Yes, at least up to extension problem.  The proof of the fact that $Conf(S-Q_k,k)$ is $K(\pi ,1)$
  provides an explicit decomposition of $Conf(S-Q_k,k)$ into a fibration of $K(\pi ',1)$'s.
- Question 2 Yes, at least in theory.  One can use the isomorphism $$H^*(BG,k)\cong Ext ^*_{k[G]}(k,k)$$ and the product structure of $Ext$ groups.  However, in practice this method is not very convenient, you would be better off to look for some ad-hoc method.